Telegram User ID Security Risks: What Could Hackers Do With It?
Considering the security and privacy of my Solana trading bot, I am trying to determine if encrypting or hashing the user Telegram ID is necessary. What potential risks could arise if the Telegram IDs are stored in plain text, and are there any best practices I should follow?
